# How to copy a list of data from one worksheet to another and spaced out

Tags: excel, vba

I am unsure how I would go about doing this, so I have a “services” worksheet that holds a list on services starting from B1 and down - this can be a infinite amount so assume the code would go to rowend.

I have another worksheet called “Data” and what I want is for the first field in B1 from “Services” to be copied into the “Data” worksheet field B12 and then for each of all the other services to be copied 7 spaces down - so a 7 space gap between each of the services in the “Services” worksheet (starting from B12 in the data worksheet)

How would I go about doing this?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried, and what problems did you run into?  This could be done using a pretty simple loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Services")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    lrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    j = 12

    For i = 1 To lrow
        ws2.Cells(j, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        j = j + 8
    Next

End Sub
```